# How do I convert my Eclipse Dynamic Web Project to a mobile application, or otherwise make it available on phone?

Tags: java, mysql, mobile

I recently finished an eclipse-made dynamic web project. It works completely fine on my computer via tomcat/localhost, but I would like to have use of it from anywhere via my phone, and not just in my browser on PC.

I've been googling around and found [auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/converting-your-web-app-to-mobile/) but from what I read this only works on applications that use html/css/javaScript exclusively.

My project in question uses jsp/servlets/java classes / tomcat/MySQL and is built in traditional MVC format .

Is there anyway I can gain access to the app from my phone? Either through converting it to a phone app, or linking to it somehow through my phone.

Any assistance is appreciated, somewhat learning disjointed on my own as I go and I know more about the code than final deployment procedure and accessing what I built / giving access to someone.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but I think that you should find a public hosting service such as AWS and deploy your webapp there. Once you get a public IP you'll be able to access from anywhere. Later on you can get a domain name. If you're thinking about authentication that's another topic and you can test it in local and remote. Java provides multiple methods. Please clarify your question

Comment: I'm not talking about authentication, I think your first suggestion of a public hosting service/ AWS is what I need though, because I'm seeking access anywhere. I'm going to sign up with AWS and see some of their info and if it suits me.

Comment: If you create a AWS account you have access to the free tier which allows to test during a year their services for free (within some limits). Have a look at the BeanStalk service where you can directly deploy your war file and they'll provide you a URL to access the service. You don't really need to worry about the underlying OS and Tomcat configuration. It also can autoscale, but to avoid unexpected costs, set it to max 1 host ;)